# Why does the runtime of my Google Scipt function depend on the project it is in?

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, runtime

I have written a very simple piece of code to copy a certain spreadsheet and place it into a folder. This function is located in a script that contains some other functions that manipulate the data in the script, the script is about 400 lines.

However, this piece of code takes extremely long to run, it even exceeds the allowed run time of a Google script. If I copy the exact same function to a new project and run it, it finishes within 10 seconds.

Why does this happen?

The piece of codes looks approximately like this:

```
function duplicateSpreadSheet() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("FILE_ID");
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID"); 
  var destinationID = file.makeCopy("Test copy", folder).getId();  
  
  Logger.log(destinationID)      
}
```

Comment: What makes you think these lines are the culprit among 400 other lines?

Comment: The lines are ran seperately from the other 400 lines, not in sequence. Literally the only difference is that the one script contains other lines of code (which should normally not influence the performance of any other loose function) and the other does not.

Comment: Without [mcve]/proof of concept, I can neither confirm nor deny your claim. If you are sure and can objectively confirm the issue, you should make a bug fix request in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: I just removed the whole script but the copy function and it still gets runtime errors. Running the exact same script in another project works just fine.
I checked the authorisation of the project, but it seems to be okay. Do you know any other possible thing that could be wrong?

Comment: So I just made a backup of my code, deleted the project, created a new one, pasted my code and everything worked. Still no clue what was the problem, but things are working again. Thanks for the help anyway TheMaster!